# Why React Native Navigation v2 icon is not showing in iOS?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I'm using new V2 of react-native-navigation, when I'm use back icons and right top bar button icons, I't works fine on android devices, but with IOS I'm not getting the image, only the blue circle.

[image]

These are the codes use generate top bar icons

```
//right button

static options(passProps) {
    return {
      topBar: {
        leftButtons: [

        ],
        rightButtons: [
          {
            id: 'settings',
            icon: require('../assets/images/symbols/settings.png'),
            disableIconTint: true
          }
        ],
      }
    };
  }
```

I'm new to react native and can someone found this issue can guide me, 
    Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem also, and this issue well buried under their GitHub issue because of outdated documentation.

I managed to fix it by adding `(left|right)Buttoncolor` inside topBar object. Example:

```
{
  topBar: {
    leftButtonColor: 'white', // here to able change the color
    rightButtonColor: 'white', // here to able change the color 

    backButton: {
      color: 'white' // for back button
    },

    leftButtons: [], // your buttons object
    rightButtons: [] // your buttons object
  }
}
```

more reference, you may take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3546).